# Видимость переменной в jquery

Tags: jquery, php

Помогите на `jQuery` получить значение переменной. Переменная объявленна в `.php` файле. А значение этой переменной нужно получить в подключённом файле `.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php выполняется на стороне сервера, а js на стороне клиента, поэтому передать значение перменной можно через:
1. Значение переменной записываем в `div`:

```
echo '<div id="php">'.$perem.'</div>';
```

и берем значение с помощью `Jquery`:

```
var php_perem = $("#php").html();
```

1. Можно также отправить ajax-ом запрос и в ответ на него получить значение переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Тяжелый случай... Ну не получишь ты в `js` переменную из `php`, если только объявить ее до выполнения твоего `jquery` скрипта в глобальной области видимости как-то вот так:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var paramName = $value;
</script>';
```